# I believe the power supply on my Dell XPS 8700 has failed

Tags: power-supply, desktop, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 8700 desktop PC I bought back in 2015. I believe the power supply has gone bad. So I went to the Dell website, entered my PC's service tag to look it up. I found the components all listed there, but their listed in a way which doesn't make sense to me. There are 2 entries in the listing of components, both with the word "power" in them - they both can't get a power supply. I don't know which one is the power supply. Here's the first entry:

- Compoment: N971H : Module,Cord,Power,125V,2M,C13 United States
- Part Number: 5120P
- Description: CORD, POWER, 125V, 6FT, SPT2, UNSHIELDED

and here's the second one:

- Compoment: 6C81Y : Module,Chassis,Pwa Integrated, 460W,8700,Power Factor Correct
- Part Number: 8Y7RX
- Description: ASSEMBLY, CHASSIS, PWA INTEGRATED, 460W, 8700, POWER FACTOR CORRECTION, BLACK

To my untrained eyes, the second one looks more promising, but I don't know for sure. Certainly none of them look like the name of power supplies like I've seen before.

Which of these is the power supply? Is it something that only Dell has or can I order it from someplace else and get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is the Dell power cord for the power supply and the second entry is the actual power supply (ASSEMBLY, CHASSIS, PWA INTEGRATED, 460W)

By the way, the part above needs to be ordered from Dell. You would need to try a local repair shop to source an alternative and guarantee it will work